# Getting a error when tring to bake it. #cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake, cake-bake

tried creating small DB and to bake it. but getting an error.

> c:\xampp\htdocs\cakeBlog>bin\cake bake
>   Exception: Plugin DebugKit could not be found.

In

> [C:\xampp\htdocs\cakeBlog\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\PluginCollection.php, line 140]

Comment: What version you are using for cakephp ?

Comment: Add this line Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]); in /config/bootstrap.php   and then try again

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in the following directory

> config/bootstrap.php

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Configure::write('DebugKit', ['forceEnable' => true]);
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```